# How to query self-referencing Flat Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has the following flattened information:

```
TRACT, ZIP, CITY, County, States
```

From right to left sits a one-to-many relationship for each column: Many Tracts in 1 Zip, Many Zips in one City, Many Cities in one County and so forth.

My goal:  I have a Zip.  Using this Zip, I need all of the Zips (inclusive) of the County this Zip resides in.  So Get County from Zip Then Ask for All Zips in the county.

My Problem:  Because the table is flattened and Denormalized, I am having issues with DISTINCT adding excessive amounts of time to query the table and otherwise causes multiple copies of Zips (referencing the Denormalization).

Does anyone have any idea how to grab this together?

Of note, this query runs excessively fast until I add DISTINCT to it:

```
Select ZIP
JOIN REF_GEOGRAPHY R on G.ZIP = R.Zip
and R.Zip in (
    Select Zip from REF_GEOGRAPHY Where County_Key in (
        Select County_Key from REF_GEOGRAPHY where Zip = 70503
    )
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your query has no `where` clause. Please post your real query.

Comment: Thanks.  The where clause is inside.  reference 70503.  70503 is the test query

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be the best way, assuming each Zip exists in only one County.

```
select distinct Zip 
from REF_GEOGRAPHY
where County = (select top 1 County from REF_GEOGRAPHY where Zip = 70503)
```

You need `distinct` unless you want duplicate results.